# Php curl passing certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am new to php and figuring out as well how curl works in webservices.

For example i have this curl command in terminal

```
Curl -i -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" \ 'https://api.com/availablecookingtime/1155/Veggies --cert ~/desktop/test.pem --key ~/desktop/key.pem:test123
```

This api requires ssl certificate to be passed in every request.

If i have a privatekey and cert.pem, and i trid this code in php:

```
$ch = curl_init(https://api.com/availablecookingtime/1155/Veggies);
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '~/desktop/test.pem');
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, '~/dekstop/key.pem');
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLPASSWORD, 'test123');
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-Type: application/json');
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
Curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

$result = curl(_exec($ch);

Echo $result; 
Echo curl_errno($ch) . PHP_EOL;
Echo curl_error($ch);
Curl_close($ch);
```

The output i get is

```
58 SSL: can't find the certificate "~/desktop/test.pem" and its private key n the keychain.
```

It doesn't seem like its grabbing the file together with the specified path. Do you have any recommendation on how i can pass the certificate from the path specified? Thanks a lot!!